# How to show "is an associate of" is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

Let *R* be a commutative ring with identity.

Show that the relation "is an associate of" is an equivalence relation on *R*.

I know that if *R* is a commutative ring with identity, then *b* is an associate of *a* if *b* = *au* for some unit *u* $\in$ *R* and for some *a, b* $\in$ *R*.

To show something is an equivalence relation is to show transitivity, symmetry, and reflexivity.

Reflexivity: As *R* is a commutative ring with identity, suppose *a, b* $\in$ *R*. Then (1) a = b and b = a. Hence, for some unit *u* $\in$ *R*, by the definition of an associate, *b* = *au* and so *a* = *bu* by (1).

I am stuck on both transitivity and associativity. Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: That reflexivity proof doesn't make much sense. I suggest you reread the definitions of the three properties, and try to "interpret" them for this particular relation before you try to prove them. For instance, the interpretation of reflexivity becomes "for any $a$ in the ring, $a$ is an associate of $a$". Prove that this is the case. Then to the same for transitivity and (not associativity, but) symmetry.

Comment: Further to @Arthur's comment, you consider $a$ to check a binary relation is reflexive, $a$ and $b$ to check it's symmetric, and $a$, $b$ and $c$ to check it's transitive, as these relations are respectively facts about arbitrary choices of $1$, $2$ and $3$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetrty: if $b=au$ for some unit $u$, then $a=bu^{-1}$ and $u^{-1}$ is a unit.

Transitivity: if $b=au$ and $c=bv$ for some units $u,v$, then $c=bv=auv=aw,$ where $w=uv$ is a unit.

Comment: sorry to bring this old thread back, I have a question on the transitivity. It's clear that $b=au$ and $c=bv$ then $c=auv \to c=a(uv)$. It's also obvious that $(uv)$ is a unit, but is it possible that $(uv)$ is not in $R$? Since rings don't necessarily need to be closed under multiplication, and I can't seem to find anything that would indicate $uv$ needs to be in $R$. In that case wouldn't transitivity not be valid, since the relation requires the unit to be in $R$? Thanks in advance!